# Google speech to Text api in android status code UNIMPLEMENTED error

Tags: java, android, ios, grpc, google-speech-api

I have been using google speech to text api in my project for more then 2 years ,it was working fine but suddenly i have started getting below error as soon as i start it.

Error to Recognize.
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: GRPC target method can't be resolved.
at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Unknown Source)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(Unknown Source)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(Unknown Source)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$500(Unknown Source)
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$3.runInContext(Unknown Source)
at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

i am using same api in both android and ios but its not working only in android and its working in ios.
It is very critical for me to resolve this error as soon as possible , any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a chance that you are using a beta version of the speech to text API that was working 2 years back but now is deprecated so if that is the reason then you need to update the API to a stable version.

You can use this link as a reference[Official documentation of Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/)

Comment: yes i was using v1beta1 and now i have changed to v1 and its working fine , thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You just need change package: google.cloud.speech.v1beta1 to google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1 or google.cloud.speech.v1. Because v1beta1 is  deprecated so it doesn't work anymore.